# Comparing Sampling Methods

Tags: sampling, method-comparison

I am interested in comparing the means generated by several different sampling methodologies. Currently I am comparing simple random, weighted random, and a non-random approach. In each case, the differing methods will be used on the same data set.

My test data-set is about 300 items.

What metrics can I use to compare estimators produced by random and non-random sampling? Are there any special considerations when comparing the two? I

Part of my hang-up involves the fact that for any given data set, the non-random method will always produce the same result, while the random samples will not.

Comment: How big is the dataset, and what kinds of estimators will you be comparing between the sampling methods? Also, what is your non-random sampling method?

Comment: I've updated the question.  The dataset is about 300 estimates. I'm interested in comparing sample means. My non-random method is a weighted-sample where I pick the few with the heaviest weightings.